# String splits to characters while adding it to tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.5

I am trying to append a tuple with string to a list, after appending tuple to the list, the tuple splits strings to its characters.

My Code:

```
def create_list():
    raw_data = ['hello world', 'hello world 1']
    new_data = []

    for data in raw_data:
        new_data.append(tuple(data))
    print(new_data)
```

Output

> [("'", 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', "'"), ("'", 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ', '1', "'")]

Expected Output

> [('hello world'), ('hello world 1')]

Comment: Try `new_data.append(("'"+str(data)+"'",))`. I'm not sure why you're concatenating the quotes

Comment: Give example output

Comment: desired output?

Comment: @roganjosh Oh Ignore it  I was just trying everything to make it work and this remained in my code.

Comment: @TaohidulIslam I have added expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can represent a tuple holding a single item with `(item,)`.  So your list could be expressed with

```
new_data = [(data,) for data in raw_data]
# [('hello world',), ('hello world 1',)]
```

The distinction between `tuple(string)` and `(string,)` is that the former is a `tuple` made from another sequence (that happens to be a string), while the latter is a tuple that contains a single string.

Comment: How to remove trailing commas?

Comment: The trailing commas aren't part of the data, they're just a part of how the data is represented.  You could print them as `print("[{}]".format(', '.join(["({})".format(", ".join(data)) for data in new_data])))`, but it isn't really necessary.  The reason we need trailing commas is because parentheses are used to group expressions.  We want `(1+2)-3` to be a valid expression, so `(1+2)` can't be a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that `tuple(s)` (with `s` a `str`) does not put `s` inside a `tuple`, but creates a `tuple` with each element being one character from `s`. Instead, use the literal `tuple` syntax `(s,)` (which is then a `tuple` of one element, namely `s`):

```
def create_list():
    raw_data = ['hello world', 'hello world 1']
    new_data = []

    for data in raw_data:
        new_data.append(("'"+str(data)+"'",))
    print(new_data)
```

Comment: Now the output goes like this `[('hello world',), ('hello world 1',)]
` What should I do to remove trailing commas?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on other's answers, another way of letting it know that you want to make a tuple with single string is by providing a list.

```
def create_list():
    raw_data = ['hello world', 'hello world 1']
    new_data = []
    for data in raw_data:
        new_data.append(tuple([data]))
    print(new_data)
```